# Setting state in the Query component of react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

So, I'm trying to set an initial state for an edit component that gets data from the server and now should be editable in the component state. But when I try to do this:

```
<Query query={POST_QUERY} variables={{ id: this.props.match.params.id }}>
    {({ data, loading, error }) => {
      this.setState({ title: data.title })
```

I get stuck in an infinite loop since this is in render. Should I not use the component state with the query component? And if not, what is the alternative?

Comment: any specific reason to setState inside `Query` component, you can directly pass it to child component

Comment: @PiyushBhati, in my case, I'm using a live form validator that needs an input controlled by state.

Comment: @rma its not good idea to use setState inside render function. You can use Query Component inside a container and pass the values to another component use `gDSFP` of that component to set it in state and there you can use your validator.

Comment: Totally agree, @PiyushBhati, and thanks. For now, the DanielRearden's solution above is working for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Whatever component needs this data as state should be rendered inside the `Query` component, and then have the data passed down to it as a prop. For example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    this.state = {
      title: props.post.title
    }
  }
}

<Query query={POST_QUERY} variables={{ id: this.props.match.params.id }}>
  {({ data, loading, error }) => {
    <MyComponent post={data.post}/>
  }}
</Query>
```

Comment: You must make sure you render MyComponent only when data.post exists and it's not loading. Unless, you will get 'undefined' values most of the times.

Comment: @daniel-rearden
Hello I have tried your solution but it did not work inside class component.  how you define QUERY component outside class .

Comment: I don't get how this answers the question. Where is it setting state after fetching the data?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `onCompleted` prop on `Query`component to set the state. See below example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    this.state = {
      isFirstRender: true
      title: props.post.title
    }
  }
  
  setTitle = title => {
    if (this.state.isFirstRender){
        this.setState({title, isFirstRender: false})
    }
  }
  
  render () {
    return <Query
             query={POST_QUERY}
             variables={{ id: this.props.match.params.id }} 
             onCompleted={data => this.setTitle(data.post.title)}
           >
      {({ data, loading, error }) => {
        <MyComponent post={data.post}/>
      }}
    </Query>
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

As the bug of `onCompleted` firing multiple times has been resolved in the latest version of `react-apollo`, we can now simply do:

```
  ...
     <Query
        query={POST_QUERY}
        variables={{ id: this.props.match.params.id }}
        onCompleted={data => this.setState({ title: data.post.title})}
     >
      {({ data, loading, error }) => {
         <MyComponent post={data.post}/>
      }}
    </Query>
  )
  ...
```

Comment: Once you set the state the component will rerender and apollo will get the data again, hence and infinite loop.

Comment: @RemigiusKalimbaJr No, actually on re-render the condition `if (this.state.isFirstRender)` will be false hence the loop will break

Comment: But will it still trigger Query , twice?

Comment: @SutikshanDubey This seems to be a bug in `react-apollo` there is an on going issue over here https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/2522

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it adequately answers the question OP asked. You may not always want to render the component inside <Query>. Some data elsewhere may rely on its completion first.