# How to avoid using setState in render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, next.js

I am using `react-apollo` to fetch data through `<Query />` and `<Mutation />`.
Thus, I want to `setState` when I get some data. I am getting the data in the render method.
Like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Query query={CAN_UPDATE_POST_QUERY} variables={{ id: this.props.router.query.postId }}>
        { payload => {

          if(payload.loading) {
            <div style={{width: '98%', textAlign: 'center', maxWidth: '1000px', margin: '50px auto'}}>Loading...</div>
          }

          if(this.isNew()){
            return (
              <PleaseSignIn>
                { me => (
                  ...something
                ) }
              </PleaseSignIn>
            )
          } else if (payload.data && payload.data.canUpdatePost) {

            // I get payload here. Here's where I want to set new state.
            this.canUpdatePost = payload.data.canUpdatePost
            this.setState({ canUpdatePost: this.canUpdatePost })


            return (
              <PleaseSignIn>
                { me => (
                  ...something
                ) }
              </PleaseSignIn>
            )


          } else {
            return (
              <div style={{width: '98%', textAlign: 'center', maxWidth: '1000px', margin: '50px auto'}}>You and your mind seems to be lost. </div>
            )
          }

        } }
      </Query>
    )
  }
```

Using `setState` in render gives me this error:
`Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

How do I think in React way? And especially, how do I get my state changed when I get payload from `react-apollo`?

**NEWBIE HERE. Sorry if silly.**

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting state in the Query component of react-apollo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437054/setting-state-in-the-query-component-of-react-apollo)

Comment: The component might rerender with each state change and updates the state each time causing further renders.

Comment: You aren't using canUpdatePost at all.

Comment: I am using canUpdatePost, just that I have stripped out that code.

Comment: You need to provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and not strip relevant parts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, you should avoid using setState in your render functions.  You should avoid having side affects (such as setting state) in your render function and instead should call other component functions to handle data change in your component.

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.

See the render() method reference in the react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render

You can create a function outside of your render method to fix this problem like so:

```
YourComponent extends React.Component {

   handleCanUpdatePost = (canUpdatePos) => {
     this.setState({ canUpdatePost })
   }

   render() {
       // Your render logic here
       // Whenever you want to setState do so by
       // calling this.handleCanUpdatePost(payload.data.canUpdatePost)
   }
}
```

You should also probably have a check to see if the value of state is going to change before setting it to avoid unnecessary re-renders:

```
handleCanUpdatePost = (canUpdatePos) => {
     this.setState((state) => { 
       if(canUpdatePos !== state.canUpdatePost) {
         return {canUpdatePost: payload.data.canUpdatePost}
       } 
     })
   }
```

Comment: Have to say it today, YOU ARE GOD ❤️

Comment: Moving a setState call from the render method to a function that the render method calls doesn't do anything other than obfuscate the setState call. The render method is still calling setState, just through the other function. The real solution is to change the component logic so that the setState call is in other lifecycle methods like componentDidMount etc